# Can we give some background image for any uiview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I need to set some background image for my view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way is to add an imageView to your view with appropriate background image. Just make sure that it is the lowest by z-order subview by adding it first or by calling `[view sendSubviewToBack:backGroundView];`

As an alternative you can set your image as a contents for your view's layer:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

...    
view.layer.contents = yourImage.CGImage;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

Comment: Oops, forgot about this option. nice one